# Parsing URL parameter in Vaadin application

Tags: java, web, url-parameters, xtend, vaadin8

I apologize for this very open question, but I did already lots of Research/test, and I can't figure out, so just thought that someone maybe already experimented the same behavior.

I have an URL as follow: http://localhost:8080/#!myapp/myparam=1234

I'm using the following just to check if my parameter is correctly passed:

```
    override enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {
        super.enter(event)
        println("PARAMETER MAP : " + event.parameterMap)
    }
```

With Chrome and Firefox, no Problem. With Internet Explorer (11), I need to refresh the page in order to see my param. By first load, i'm just having an empty map.

Should the parameter be passed/parsed differently for IE?

(I'm using Vaadin 8)

Edit: After first load on IE, parameters actually also disappear from the URL, and I end up with following URL: http://localhost:8080/#!myapp

Edit2: it seems actually to be a problem with a form which we "bypass" using the onload JS method. The form contains:

```
    <body onload="document.forms['login_form'].submit()">
    <div>
        <center>
            <form name="login_form" method="post" action="">
                <input hidden="hidden" type="submit" value=""/>
            </form>
        </center>
    </div>
    </body>
```

So actually the question is: why IE looses parameters when such a form comes into play?

Comment: _Should the parameter be passed/parsed differently for IE?_ No, one of the main points using Vaadin is to avoid such things. Maybe it is some problem with IE11 or Vaadin has some bug for code generation to it.